# Why isnt my entire dropdown list displaying?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, nav

I'm trying to figure out with my drop-down list within my nav is not displaying. I 
am also trying to understand how to i would render the drop-down list as a class and how it would be specified in the CSS to not get it confused with any of my of unordered lists. Can someone please help and possibly add a class to the dropdown list so i know how to display it?

```
Here is my code in Jfiddle:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/CheckLife/rzxxb2kb/4/

Comment: Put your code in the post please instead of linking to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css you have:

```
/*Dropdown Nav */

ul li ul li {
    display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

The problem here is that you're setting each individual "li" element to display none, so you're hiding each individual list item. If you show/hide the whole unordered list, then your elements will appear. Additionally, you probably want to remove position:absolute so that they stack vertically

```
/*Dropdown Nav */

ul li ul {
    display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

EDIT:
In order to address the issue of the list pushing all content down, I recommend not using an ul. Instead you could put each a tag in a div and do the following:

HTML:

```
      <li onmouseover="newText()"><a href="#">Players</a>               
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  // The below was copied from your other css
  background-color: #3b63d3;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px groove #141e38;
}
li:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: no i understand that.... but what im saying is i want the effect to be able to drop down over other elements. thats why i put absolute because on my entire webpage when i just put block, the entire drop-down displays but it pushes the other elements below it @sam

Comment: @CheckLife Check my edit, as I recommend not putting the dropdown portion in a ul

Comment: I see what you mean @sam, see for some reason i like it when things are difficult so i can fully understand all possible outcomes! hahahaha thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/rzxxb2kb/5/

Its the `position: absolute;` on `ul li:hover ul li` change it to `position: relative;`

```
/*Dropdown Nav */

ul li ul li{
    display: none;
}
ul li:hover ul li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: when i put relative it pushes all my other content down

Answer (score 0):

W3Schools shows how to create Nav bars with drop down functionality

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp

Comment: yea ive been on there...and in one of their examples they use the absolute positioning to do what im trying to do....my problem is its only showing one of my dropdown items

Comment: If you notice at the bottom of the web-page, the example shows that the drop-down items are anchor tags and there parent is a div tag.

Your example uses an UL list and your CSS is only pointing to the LI inside (not the UL) which is picking up your other UL styling too (so its horizontal and not vertical), that's what is conflicting so its only going to show one LI child (your last) you can test this by adding `ul li:hover ul li:first-of-type` to see the first.

If you insist on using two lists then i would consider adding classes so each list can be styled independently.

Comment: when i replaced "ul li:hover ul li " with what you had it did the same thing, the only difference was that it gave me the first "player"  i listed

Comment: are you understanding that I want the main nav bar to be horizontal and the dropdown to be vertical?

Comment: Correct i was using that as an example of whats happening. Use classes on you ul and li elements to stop the conflicting CSS or use the great example on W3Schools.